# How to create javax.el.ExpressionFactory in Google App Engine to use Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to upgrade to hibernate validator version 6 on my Google App Engine app, which [needs javax.el](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-uel), so I added `org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b10` to my dependencies.

However, this is not used:

In the local dev environment, I can create a new `ExpressionFactory` with `ExpressionFactory.newInstance()`. The `ExpressionFactory` is from the local Jetty installation `jetty93/jetty-distribution/lib/apache-jsp/org.mortbay.jasper.apache-el-8.0.33.jar` and it returns the implementation `org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl` from the same jar.

In the deployed GAE environment, the `ExpressionFactory` is from `java8_runtime/runtime-shared.jar!/javax/el/ExpressionFactory.class` but `ExpressionFactory.newInstance()` still tries to get a `org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl`, even though `com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl` is present.

In both environments, I can manually load a `com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl` from `WEB-INF/lib/javax.el-3.0.1-b10.jar`, so it is present in the classpath:

```
final Constructor<ExpressionFactoryImpl> constructor = com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.class.getConstructor();
final ExpressionFactoryImpl expressionFactory = constructor.newInstance();
```

- Why is the GAE environment so keen on loading `org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl` even though the reference implementation `com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl` is on the classpath?
- How can I make GAE load  the existing `ExpressionFactoryImpl` so I can create a hibernate ValidatorFactory? Do I have to manually supply a [`MessageInterpolator`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-custom-message-interpolation) so I can supply the correct `ExpressionFactoryImpl`?

Comment: Hi, do you have 'com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl' dependencies specified in your XML file? Try providing configuration details.

<param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name> 
<param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>

Comment: I added <context-param> <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value> 
  </context-param> to my web.xml, didn't make a difference...

Comment: I think a similar issue was reported and solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23932668/9738014). Give that a try. If you still run into issues provide your configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it by adding a system property to appengine-web.xml:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="javax.el.ExpressionFactory" value="com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl" />
</system-properties>
```

An other possibility could be to add the file 'META-INF/services/javax.el.ExpressionFactory' with the contents:

```
com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46582248/2080575)

I didn't test the second method, but it has the highest priority in the source of apache-el ExpressionFactory, while the system property is only the third try.

Comment: Thank you - after a lot of searching for a solution, adding the `system-properties` entry worked. I had previously tried adding the file as described into `META-INF` however this didn't solve the issue when using Java 8 Standard for me.